# how to use react-router for dynamic url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building extremely stretchable react app and I am using SSR fro SEO.
but I don't know how to handle URL

Like: user can directly land on this URL, **domian.com/delhi/cardiologist**

In the backend, I have a system of identifying the components for URL, which is for this case is "Speciality" component in "Location: component

I can't go like this

```
<Rout path={"delhi"}>
    <Location/>
</Route>
```

cause for this case it's Delhi. but for another user, it will be a different city name, I want to reflect the different city in URL but to render same component due best SEO.
SEO is heart of my app.

I am literally new to this kind of things. 
please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding some structure to the path that makes it easier for you to find the location, say:

```
<Route path='/search/:city/:specialty' component={Specialty} />
```

So this would match `domian.com/search/delhi/cardiologist`. You can customize it to whatever makes sense, it could even be a short letter like just `/go/` if you are concerned about URL length because of SEO.

Then, inside the Specialty component, you can use `match.params.city` and `match.params.specialty` to get the parameters that you are looking for:

```
function Specialty({ match }) {
  const { city, specialty } = match.params;

  return (
    <p>Search for {specialty} in the city of {city}</p>
  );
}
```

You could still implement a *catch-all* route using the path that you want:

```
<Route path='/:city/:specialty' component={Specialty} />
```

However, that would require always setting the route at the end, so that it only lands on your `<Specialty />` component if it doesn't match any other path that you have.

Comment: Instead of function can we have a class?